# Limiting the number of characters in a div has specific class

Tags: javascript, html

I have some set of *div* which has a class name. Here I want to control/limit the number of characters to be displayed in the *div* based on the class name using JavaScript. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using any particular javascript framework such as jQuery? Or do you want a plain javascript solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the jQuery solution for limiting the elements with `.myclass`to 200 chars:

```
var myDiv = $('.myclass');
myDiv.text(myDiv.text().substring(0,200));
```

The pure JavaScript solution (for all browsers that don't support `getElementByClassname`) would look like this:

```
var i;
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
  if(divs[i].className == 'myclass') {
    divs[i].innerHTML = divs[i].innerHTML.substring(0,200);
  }
}
```

Note that the pure JavaScript method may create invalid HTML if the divs contain markup. The correct way would be to iterate over the child nodes in the div.

Comment: Is it not better to use `myDiv.html(myDiv.html().substring(0,200));`? I think `.text(bla)` will remove any formatting, right?

Comment: You may create invalid markup and undesired effects too if you use the jQuery html() method instead of text(). For example if you have an opening <strong> tag and cut off the closing tag. The solution becomes more complex if the div needs to contain markup. If you want to preserve the markup, you have to iterate recursively over the element tree inside the div until the char limit is reached.

Comment: That is a very good point! One worth raising in case Ra wants to keep formatting. Think I must be going dumb... usually I would think of things like this!

Comment: yes.I just want to keep the formatting of the text. And it works.. thanks everybody.

Comment: As chiborg rightly said, if it is keeping the formatting then you risk having invalid HTML. As far as I know this can result in some browsers going into "Quirks mode". If this is a risk you are willing to take then fair enough, but it is probably best just to use `.text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the substring() method in JavaScript. Details on usage are in *[JavaScript String substring()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)*.

If you are using jQuery, select by the class and run the sub string method.

Answer (score 0):

#### A version that honours existing child elements

I came across this Q&A, but I was looking for something that *would* handle child elements correctly, rather than just a sub-string slice. For those that may need this, here is what I put together.

Basically it recursively steps through child elements, clones and appends them to a new container — all the while totaling up the number of "words" it finds (i.e., text content split by spaces).

http://jsfiddle.net/D8LEx/2/

Once it reaches its word limit, it will stop processing/appending new nodes. If the content of the final text node will breach the word limit, the node's text value is sliced to meet the requirement.

The code expects the class name provided to be the containing element of mainly text nodes with some other elements mixed in. For example, `wrapping-element` would be the element to target:

```
<p class="wrapping-element">
  Rude alert! An electrical fire has knocked out my voice-recognition unicycle!
  Many Wurlitzers are <strong>missing from my database!</strong>
  <a href="#shop">Abandon shop!</a>
  This is not a <i>daffodil!</i>
</p>
```

#### The code

I've tried to keep this a succinct as possible. It works in all modern browsers — mainly those that support `getElementsByClassName` and `cloneNode`:

```
var wordlimit = (function(){
  var clonempty = function( elm ){
    var doppel = elm.cloneNode();
        doppel.innerHTML = '';
    return doppel;
  };
  var wordsmith = function( elm, out, opts ){
    var i, l, kids = elm.childNodes, kid, txt, wrd, tnd;
    for (i=0, l=kids.length; i<l && opts && opts.limit; i++) {
      if ( (kid = kids[i]) && kid.nodeType === 1 ) {
        wordsmith( kid, out.appendChild( clonempty(kid) ), opts );
      }
      else if ( kid && kid.nodeType === 3 ) {
        txt = kid.nodeValue;
        wrd = txt.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(' ');
        if ( wrd.length >= opts.limit ) {
          tnd = document.createTextNode( wrd.slice(0, opts.limit).join(' ') );
          out.appendChild( tnd );
          opts.limit -= wrd.length;
          if ( opts.limit < 0 && opts.ellipsis ) {
            out.appendChild( document.createTextNode('...') );
          }
          opts.limit = 0;
        }
        else {
          opts.limit -= wrd.length;
          out.appendChild( document.createTextNode(txt) );
        }
      }
    }
    return out;
  }
  return function(classname, limit, ellipsis){
    var i, l, elms = document.getElementsByClassName(classname), elm, out;
    for (i=0, l=elms.length; i<l; i++) {
      elm = elms[i];
      out = wordsmith( elm, clonempty(elm), {
        limit: limit,
        ellipsis: ellipsis
      });
      elm.parentNode.insertBefore( out, elm );
      elm.parentNode.removeChild( elm );
    }
  };
})();
```

#### Usage

To call it is quite simply:

```
wordlimit(class-name :string, word-limit :int, add-ellipsis :boolean)
```

So:

```
wordlimit('wrapping-element', 40, true)
```

#### Disclaimer

The above could be improved to support complex CSS selectors, or just allow the provision of the actual element(s) to work with. The current version does support multiple elements with the specified class name.

> **Please note:** This code will remove the original element, and replace with a newly fashioned clone. Because the code relies on [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode), any event listeners that are already in place will be lost, as per this snippet from the linked MDN page:

> *Cloning a node copies all of its attributes and their values, including intrinsic (in–line) listeners. It does not copy event listeners added using addEventListener() or those assigned to element properties (e.g. node.onclick = fn).*

> It goes without saying that any existing live element references to the elements being modified by this code will also be broken. *[Why mention it then? Ed.]*

> I had no need to worry about keeping the existing elements, but if you require this it should be quite simple to rewrite the code to work on existing elements; rather than clone and destroy.