# How can I the limit inner text of a div to 175 characters?

Tags: jquery

I have a div area that has an arbitrary number of characters. I want to limit the amount of characters that show up in there to 175 characters. I mostly found examples on how to do this for an input text box or text area, but not a div. How can I do it?

This is my code I am trying to limit to 175 characters:

```html
<div class="some-area">
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
</div>
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448856/limiting-the-no-of-characters-in-a-div-has-specific-class

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the [the form of text() that takes a function](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) and write something like:

```
$("div.some-area").text(function(index, currentText) {
    return currentText.substr(0, 175);
});
```

Comment: `return text.substr(0, 175) + '...';` to have the ellipses.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this will not work for HTML content inside that div, it will most likely break tags

Answer (score 14):

Replace div with the correct identifier for your content:

```
$("div").text($(this).text().substr(0, 175)+'...');
```

Remove the ellipses from the end if desired. I would recommend leaving them to let your users know that the text was shortened.  If you are just trying to limit the text to 175 without any notice, then you may choose to remove them in that case as well.

Answer (score 4):

I just did this for one of my projects. I found [this](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/) great plugin.

```
$('some-area').expander({
    slicePoint:175
});
```

Comment: Great plugin! That's what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just cutting it off at 175 characters, add an ellipsis to the div if the text runs over the maximum width: https://web.archive.org/web/20110828173959/http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/ellipsis

Answer (score 0):

```
var textis="";textis=$(".some-area").html().substring(0, 175);$(".some-area").html(textis);
```