# How can I make a div contain a certain number of characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a contentEditable div. I want to make its value size 10, so the div can't contain more than 10 characters. Is it possible?

If yes, how can I do it in HTML or JavaScript?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983912/how-to-limit-inner-text-of-div-to-175-characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really do it in HTML, as there's no size attribute that works that way, like when using a `INPUT:TEXT` element.  So you would have to use JavaScript.  Here is an example in jQuery:

#### jQuery:

```
$('#my-div.contentEditable').text(function(idx, txt) {
    return txt.substr(0, 10);
});
```

You could then additionally use CSS to ensure that you have a **tight** fit around your text, since different fonts/font sizes would yield different widths, despite the 10 character constraint:

#### CSS:

```
#my-div.contentEditable{
  padding: 0;
  left-margin: auto;
  right-margin: auto;
}
```