# How to restrict the user from typing more than certain characters in a editable div or Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have an editable div and iFrame. I require that the user must not be able to type more than 100 characters per line. The user can enter infinite number of lines all having maximum 100 characters.

Also the user can go back to any line, using arrow keys and enter more text in case that line had less that 100 characters.

How to perform this?

EDIT:
This needs to be like in real time as the user types.

Comment: whats wrong with [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML_Elements/textarea)?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448856/limiting-the-no-of-characters-in-a-div-has-specific-class

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mydivid').keypress(function(e){
    if($(this).html().length > 20)
        e.preventDefault();
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JRrme/)

Comment: I need to restrict perline not the whole HTMl and also in real time

Answer (score 0):

you can check with jquery `keyup` event.

```
$('DIV ID').keyup(function(){
  data = $.trim($('DIV ID')).html().length; 

  if(data > 100) // or add condition as per your requirement
  {
  }
  else
 {
   alert('Your message')
 }
});
```

Comment: I need to restrict perline not the whole HTMl and also in real time.

Comment: Can it be possible to pass the `data` variable to `for` loop  after converting it(`data`) to behave as an array to show each line as value than I think we can restrict the user to enter text upto specific length.
Its just an idea that just knocked on my head... I have no experienced on it...... Please let me know if it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var max_length = 100;
$("#div-editable").keypress(function(){
    var return_state = true;
    $(this).find("div").each(function(){
        if($(this).text().length >= max_length)
        {
            return_state = false;
            //break;
        }
    });
    return return_state;
});
```

});

Just change max_length to your needs.

Also you can use Trim if you want to allow spacing on start and end of the text.

You can check this on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jYLXX/1/)

Comment: I need to restrict perline not the whole HTMl and also in real time

Comment: @BhumiSinghal Just found out that div with contentEditable splits new lines into div elements

Comment: This happens only in Chrome. Not for FireFox and in IE they beocme P tags