# Maximum amount of characters in a div/paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a 'New system' and I'd like the home page to show up to 300 characters per news article, and add an hyperlink "Read more" automatically at the end of the 300 characters (if needed). However, how would I do this?

I do not know what it is called and I couldn't find an answer on my question by just googling. I did find similair questions, like: [Limiting the no of characters in a div has specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448856/limiting-the-no-of-characters-in-a-div-has-specific-class) But it doesn't completely fit my question.

Here is an example what it should look like:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cil**...Read more**

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what you can't understand from the link?

Comment: The above link what you have given is the function written in jquery.

Comment: Either do what they did in the other question or use something like https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string prune or https://gist.github.com/mseeley/1637329

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## jQuery way:

If you want to put only 300 characters, then you must use jQuery framework or pure Javascript.

***Note:*** *just change `#your-div-id` and put your div ID.*

```
var myDiv = $('#your-div-id');
myDiv.text(myDiv.text().substring(0,300))
```

.

## Pure JavaScript way:

***Note:*** *just change `#your-div-id` and put your div ID.*

```
var i;
var divs = document.getElementById('#your-div-id');
for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
  if(divs[i].className == 'myclass') {
    divs[i].innerHTML = divs[i].innerHTML.substring(0,300);
  }
}
```

---

## Add `Read More` at the end:

if you want to add `Read More` at the end of each substringed paragraph, then you need to use pure Javascript or jQuery ways:

**jQuery way:**

```
var myDiv = $('#your-div-id');
myDiv.text(myDiv.text().substring(0,300) + '<a href="#">Read more</a>')
```

.

**Pure JavaScript way:**

```
var i;
var divs = document.getElementsById('#your-div-id');
for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
  if(divs[i].className == 'myclass') {
    divs[i].innerHTML = divs[i].innerHTML.substring(0,300) + '<a href="#">Read more</a>';
  }
}
```

---

## FYI

Also there is a pure CSS way to substring text in box, but it has no option to manually put character limit:

**CSS way:**

You can achieve this by pure CSS:

```
#your-div {
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

it will automatically cut text and put `...` at the end of the box.

*Please note, that it will not restrict browser to put only 300 characters. It will just fill the box.*

Comment: +1 for complete answer with code to boot. Although the css answer is not really an answer to his question.

Comment: @TigOldBitties I agree with you, just wrote all possible ways to give more understanding for `stefan1294`

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't get a better answer.

Comment: @zur4ik AFAIK, there is no document.getElement**s**ById in vanilla javascript. There is document.getElementById() which returns a single element with that id ince id is supposed to be unique.

Comment: @MohammedShareefC yes you are right. It was type error. updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can try like this....

Check the length of the div, if >300 make a substring and make the div content with substring+"...".
Append to the div a link with a listener that replace all content of the div with the original content, or just add a link to the complete article.

```
var str = $('#mydiv').text();
if(len>300){
  var new_str = str.subtstr(0,300); 
  new_str += '<div data="'+str+'">' +  new_str + '... </div>';

  var newDiv = $(new_str);
  var link_read_more = $('<a class="read_more">Read more</a>');
  link_read_more.click(function(){
    var originaltext = $(this).parent().attr('data');
    $(this).parent().html(originaltext);
  });
  newDiv.append(link_read_more);
}
```