# Is there a character limit on what can be returned to a div?

Tags: html, limits

I am attempting to pull from a field in an SQL DB for several operations each are broken down into subsets for the end users. My report seems to bomb out at about 4200 characters in a single subset and 7500 characters total of all subsets. Please keep in mind that these subsets can consist of a variable of characters and have multiple subsets. All I have been able to find is how to set a limit nothing to the effect of if there is a default limit.

Comment: This is not a hard limit of HTML. Look elsewhere, probably in the SQL or access of such.

Comment: html has no limits. your BROWSER probably does, but will most likely choke itself to death before admitting to one.

Comment: Read this - [Maximum amount of characters in a div/paragraph tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425555/maximum-amount-of-characters-in-a-div-paragraph-tag)