# Readmore option automatically display after some character

Tags: javascript

As my question is like repeat in stackoverflow; still i am not finding any final solution. 
I want to display **readmore** option if the div contain character is greater than 300.Again after click on **readmore**, the rest content will display.

I have tried something by searching google, please overlook my code and help me to fix it.

HTML code :

```
<div class="only-so-big" id="shw">
    This one has way too much content to show. Best be saving it for those who want to read everything in here.
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi THE END!
  </div>
```

Script code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var str = $('#shw').text();
  if(len>300){
    var new_str = str.subtstr(0,300); 
    new_str += '<div data="'+str+'">' +  new_str + '... </div>';

    var newDiv = $(new_str);
    var link_read_more = $('<a class="read_more">Read more</a>');
    link_read_more.click(function(){
      var originaltext = $(this).parent().attr('data');
      $(this).parent().html(originaltext);
    });
    newDiv.append(link_read_more);
  }
      </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425555/maximum-amount-of-characters-in-a-div-paragraph-tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 var str = $('#shw').text();
 
 if (str.length > 300) {
  
  $('#shw').empty().html(str.substr(0,300));
  
  var moreLink = '<a href="#" class="read_more">Read more</a>';
  $('#shw').append(moreLink);
  
  $('.read_more').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#shw').empty().html(str);
  });
  
 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="only-so-big" id="shw">
    This one has way too much content to show. Best be saving it for those who want to read everything in here.
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi THE END!
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @webmazz, your given code is working correctly. You save my time. Thanx once again.